# is there a way to see method's comment in netbeans like in eclipse?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.3

On Eclipse when i point the mouse up to a method it shows the method's comment (java doc), is there any way to do some thing like that in netbeans (7.3) without putting the cursor in the method middle and hitting Ctrl + Space?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the javadoc in Netbeans by clicking on the method and press `Ctrl+Shift+Space`.
[Here](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf) You have more NetBeans shortcuts.

Comment: Don't thanks, just accept, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177292/comments-saying-thank-you-remind-op-to-accept-answer .

Answer (score 0):

It is supported in NetBeans 8.

`Show Javadoc as tooltip while hovering (Note: hold CTRL-key) (Issue 95691)`

See http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB80#Editor_2